# How to declare a function: as a separate function or in the same function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello Stackoverflow people,

The questions, is about code style and code maintainability, rather than search for some errors.

Let's assume that I am creating some module for node.js. This module, is exporting only one object, let's call this object "FileParser". During file parsing, there can be different preprocessing functions. They are very unique, and I am not planning to reuse them in other parts of the application.

Since, this module is exporting only one function - **my question is next**:

In case I have some utility functions for this module, should I define this functions in the function which is exported, or they should be defined outside this function.

Basically- this:

```
var FileParser = function(){
}

FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function(){
  var utilityFunction = function(){
    //do some work, maybe even return values
  }

  //do some other work.
  utilityFunction();

  //do more other work
}
module.exports.FileParser = FileParser;
```

or this:

```
var FileParser = function(){
}

FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function(){
  //do some work before calling function
  utilityFunction();
  //do more and more work after calling function
}

function utilityFunction(){
 //body of function goes here, maybe even returning some value
}
module.exports.FileParser = FileParser;
```

What is more readable, especially if there are few utility functions.

Thanks,
-D

Comment: I believe that the first example is wrong, cause you are declaring a function inside another one, do you really using in this way?

Comment: you can use this that way, especially if you will use it as callback, for example, or you plan to use in in more than one place in the function.

Comment: One defines the function each time the class is instantiated, while the other only defines it once. I don't see what "readable" has to to do with this, it's more about functionality. In the one where it is redefined each time, it has access to `this` where as the other way it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

If `utilityFunction` is not used as a closure (i.e. it does not access variables declared in the `methodToExport` function), there is no good reason to declare it inside that other function.

Put it outside, it makes the `methodToExport` shorter (and therefore more readable).

Since it resides in your "local" module scope, you don't even need to bother about global namespace pollution. If the number of utility functions grows, you might consider grouping them appropriately, e.g. by using the revealing module pattern.

Comment: Oh, at last good answer. At least i heard arguments why should i put it outside.:)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, your function will be declared each time `methodToExport` is called, in the second you will have global function. Maybe you can use some kind of closure:

```
FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function() {
    function utilityFunction () { 
        //do some work, maybe even return values
    }
    return function () { // This is the real function, the one which will be export!
        //do some other work
        utilityFunction () ;
        //do more other work
    } ;
} () ;
```

Maybe there is a better way, but I would have done things like that!

Comment: emmm, that example was just to show what is possible. let me edit it, so it will be more clear:)

Comment: @dimko1 Yes it works as I said, I'll add comments on my post.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is flexible enough to permit such thing, the declaration bellow, works but is not a good pratice in my point of view.

```
var FileParser = function(){

}

FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function(){
    var utilityFunction = function(){
        //do some work
    }
    utilityFunction();
}

module.exports.FileParser = FileParser;
```

You're declaring and call inside a function, but is more clearly to do this inside the declaration of your FileParser object.

So, you have good pattern of declaration the [Revealing Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/blog/tag/revealing-module-pattern/), proposed by Addy Osmani.

```
var FileParser = function(){
    var utilityOne = function(){
    }

    this.methodToExport = function(){
       // do some work 
       utilityOne();
    }
}

module.exports.FileParser = FileParser;
```

This able you to hide some utility function as a kind of encapsulation, and show only the important functions outside.

Comment: added more comments:) the question is more about the way how you are organising the code

Comment: I tryied to improve... take a look again please.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask about this, but I would recommend that you place your code inside an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so there's one less variable in the top level closure, like this:

```
module.exports.FileParser = (function(){
    var FileParser = function(){};
    // Do your stuff
    return FileParser;
})();
```

This saves your having to create a global variable for FileParser.

Now as for the question which you did ask -- should the utility function be defined within the exported function or outside of it -- my answer depends on whether you're only exporting a single function, or multiple. In your case, since you're only exporting a single function, my answer is that as long as you have a choice, I prefer the utility function defined outside because its closure scope is smaller that way. By "as long as you have a choice", I mean that your utility function isn't using anything defined within `methodToExport`.

```
module.exports.FileParser = (function(){
    var FileParser = function(){};
    var utilityOne = function(){};

    FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function(){
        // do some work 
        utilityOne();
    }
    return FileParser;
})();
```

A smaller closure scope doesn't make much of a difference in most circumstances, but the following is an example where it does.

```
module.exports.FileParser = (function(){
    var FileParser = function(){};


    FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function(){
        var longArray = [ /* ... */ ];
        var utilityOne = function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                console.log("Hello");
            },1000);
        };
        utilityOne();
    }
    return FileParser;
})();
```

In the above example, `longArray` is in the closure of `utilityOne()` even though it isn't needed. The setTimeout's reference to `longArray` prevents it from being garbage collected.

```
module.exports.FileParser = (function(){
    var FileParser = function(){};
    var utilityOne = function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log("Hello");
        },1000);
    };

    FileParser.prototype.methodToExport = function(){
        var longArray = [ /* ... */ ];
        utilityOne();
    }
    return FileParser;
})();
```

Moving the `utilityOne()` definition out of the method definition shrinks its closure scope and allows the `longArray` to be garbage collected.